# How to put my published properties into the specified category of Object Inspector?

Tags: delphi, properties, delphi-2010, categories

I have my own visual component. It has many published properties and events. I want them to be shown in the specified standard categories of Object Inspector at design-time (**Visual**, **Layout**, **Drag Drop / Docking**, **Linkage** etc).

Now all my properties are in the **Miscellaneous** category.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use **RegisterPropertyInCategory** function, defined in the DesignIntf. [Example](http://etutorials.org/Programming/mastering+delphi+7/Part+II+Delphi+Object-Oriented+Architectures/Chapter+9+Writing+Delphi+Components/A+Complex+Graphical+Component/).